# No Wifi-Adapter found on new Lenovo Yoga C930 with Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, lenovo

Hello and merry Christmas,

I have a new Lenovo Yoga C930 and try to install Ubuntu 18.10 on this machine, but Wifi is not working.
I'm not a Linux professional but I tried a lot the last hours (also with the answers of this forum).

First of all, Wifi is turned on in Bios (I double checked this). If I open the Wifi Settings the message "Kein Funknetzwerkadapter gefunden" is shown. A connection via cable LAN (over USB-C) works out of the box.

```
lspci | grep Wireless
6b:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
```

I was wondering about this output:

```
rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
4: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

I'm not sure if ideapad_wlan or phy0 is the correct one.

Maybe lsmod is also interesting:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
iwlmvm                368640  0
iwlwifi               294912  1 iwlmvm
mac80211              794624  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              663552  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
cdc_ether              16384  0
usbnet                 45056  1 cdc_ether
r8152                  61440  0
mii                    16384  2 usbnet,r8152
snd_usb_audio         225280  2
snd_usbmidi_lib        32768  1 snd_usb_audio
thunderbolt           122880  0
rfcomm                 77824  4
cmac                   16384  1
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
arc4                   16384  2
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_soc_skl           102400  0
snd_soc_skl_ipc        61440  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_ipc        16384  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_dsp        32768  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_hda_codec_realtek   106496  1
snd_hda_ext_core       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_soc_acpi           16384  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core          229376  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          40960  3
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  7 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_skl
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             208896  0
kvm                   622592  1 kvm_intel
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
uvcvideo               98304  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
btusb                  45056  0
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
videobuf2_common       45056  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
input_leds             16384  0
btintel                20480  1 btusb
serio_raw              16384  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
videodev              188416  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
bluetooth             548864  31 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
hid_sensor_als         16384  1
hid_sensor_accel_3d    16384  1
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
hid_sensor_trigger     16384  4 hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  2 hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d
kfifo_buf              16384  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
snd                    81920  25 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
hid_sensor_iio_common    16384  3 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d
soundcore              16384  1 snd
ucsi_acpi              16384  0
industrialio           69632  7 industrialio_triggered_buffer,hid_sensor_trigger,kfifo_buf,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d
media                  40960  2 videodev,uvcvideo
joydev                 20480  0
mei_me                 40960  0
hid_multitouch         20480  0
typec_ucsi             32768  1 ucsi_acpi
ecdh_generic           24576  2 bluetooth
8250_dw                16384  0
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
idma64                 20480  0
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
virt_dma               16384  1 idma64
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
typec                  32768  1 typec_ucsi
ideapad_laptop         32768  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
int3403_thermal        16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
acpi_pad              180224  0
int3400_thermal        16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
algif_skcipher         16384  0
af_alg                 24576  1 algif_skcipher
dm_crypt               40960  1
hid_sensor_custom      20480  0
wacom                 106496  0
usbhid                 49152  1 wacom
hid_sensor_hub         20480  5 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_iio_common,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_custom
hid_generic            16384  0
i915                 1740800  12
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
aesni_intel           200704  4
nvme                   32768  3
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
cryptd                 24576  4 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
i2c_i801               28672  0
nvme_core              81920  5 nvme
drm                   458752  5 drm_kms_helper,i915
i2c_hid                20480  0
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
hid                   126976  6 i2c_hid,wacom,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_sensor_hub,hid_generic
wmi                    24576  3 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof,ideapad_laptop
video                  45056  2 ideapad_laptop,i915
```

Any ideas or do I need to post more information?

Comment: Wifi is enabled in Bios. The only key on the keyboard that is related to wifi seems to be the "flight mode" key. No difference if i press it, and check afterwards with rfkill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual fix has been to blacklist the ideapad-laptop module but there is another way to fix

```
sudo apt install git dkms build-essential
git clone -b 4.18 https://github.com/jeremyb31/ideapad-laptop.git
sudo dkms add ./ideapad-laptop
sudo dkms install ideapad-laptop/1.0
echo "options ideapad_laptop override_has_hw_rfkill_switch=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad_laptop.conf
```

Check `mokutil --sb-state` if it says the Secure Boot is enabled, you will need to disable when you reboot in BIOS settings.  Please leave the Secure Boot signing keys alone

Ubuntu 18.04 users that have the 4.15 kernels should use

```
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/ideapad-laptop.git
```

New code courtesy of user ryuo on spotchat IRC

Comment: Thx for your help. It works like a charm out of the box!

Comment: If i did the cloned the 4.18 instead of 4.15,  how do i undo the changes to do 4.15

Comment: `sudo dkms remove ideapad-laptop/1.0 --all` then `cd ideapad-laptop && git checkout master`, `cd ` then run sudo dkms add and install commands from the answer

Comment: @Jeremy31 were you trying to post two **different** links to your github directory? 'cause the links look the same. You also say blacklist ideapad-laptop, but then you install your ideapad-laptop git code... so which is it? I'm confused.

Comment: @heynnema I needed 2 branches to handle 4.15 and 4.18 source code.  I don't recall saying to blacklist ideapad-laptop since I was provided with the source code from ryu0

Comment: @Jeremy31 Oh, now I see the difference... the links **are** the same, the first link is for a different branch! Silly me.

Comment: do you know if this will work for a Yoga C940 as well? A blacklist ideapad_laptop in blacklist.conf did not work ; (

Comment: @megloff You might want to try 19.10 as I think some new code in the 5.3 kernel should fix the wifi block