# Lenovo C930 WiFi card not recognized. Fix?

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I just installed Ubuntu 18.10 on my Lenovo C930. It doesn’t recognize its WiFi card in Ubuntu.

Fix was identified as:

sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop

But this needs to be done every time I boot into Ubuntu.  Where to I place this to take effect every boot?

Thanks!

Note this is not a duplicate of [This Thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104218/no-wifi-adapter-found-on-new-lenovo-yoga-c930-with-ubuntu-18-10.).  This question addresses how to avoid the need to modprobe every time I boot which is not covered.

Comment: `modprobe -r` removes module, so why not add it to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` as a blacklisted module, ie. add line 'blacklist ideapad-laptop`

Comment: Note this is not a duplicate.  This question addresses how to avoid the need to modprobe every time I boot which is not covered.

Comment: With my fix, you don't have to blacklist ideapad-laptop as blacklisting it might result in some FN combos no longer working

Comment: Jeremy31 I like the idea of a more "limited" fix.  However I hate messing with Secure Boot on Bitlocker PCs.  I know my key but it is just one more think I need to worry about.   If I see poor performance or other devices disabled I will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`modprobe -r` removes a [kernel] module, so you can blacklist it to avoid it's being loaded in the future.

add the line

> blacklist ideapad-laptop

to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` so it doesn't get as a kernel module.

Comment: Please note `modprobe -r` can cause other modules that depend on ideapad-laptop to also be removed when executed.  They may also need to be blacklisted too.

Comment: Thanks guiverc.  And handsome samoyed you have there. I have 2 floofs myself!