# WLAN hard blocked but working on windows

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, 18.04, intel-wireless

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 + windows10 dual boot.
Recently my ubuntu crashed and i had to run boot-repair using a live disc.
Since then my wifi on ubuntu hasn't been working. However the wifi works fine on windows.

[image]

I made sure the WLAN is enabled in BIOS.
I am using lenovo ideapad 500-15ISK.
I can't turn it on from the UI, no matter how many times i try.

Also, some off my hot keys like volume up/down, mute, touchpad disable and airplane mode don't seem to be working.

I reckon if the reason for hard block is a constant airplane mode signal to the network card somehow

here is the detailed output of my network card: https://gist.github.com/fireballpoint1/52f897a9621b75468fe9d99902def3d0

*Edit 1*

I had repaired the crash using a live disc and the wifi was working fine for that. Is it possible to do something using a live disc to repair this ?

Comment: If the technique at the duplicate doesn't work for some reason, I'll retract the duplicate and we'll take another look.

Comment: Make sure `hotkeys` are enabled in your BIOS, then hit the `F7` key. See if that toggles airplane mode.

Comment: @chili555 yeah i tried that already. didnt work. please remove duplicate tag

Comment: @heynnema I tried enabling and disabling them, the hotkey makes no difference. Even my volume keys don't work

Comment: Try my solution at https://askubuntu.com/a/1104240/300665 remove blacklist ideapad-laptop from /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf